# Update some chrome extension files from own server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update

I am writing a chrome extension in which some script and an XML file in which I data is to be read by the script are changed almost twice per day. If I include a link to it on every page load, my hosting server load will probably suffer. Isn't it possible to get a copy of my script and XML Files each time that the browser is launched in order to update them in my extension ?
PS : I resorted to this solution since it is not possible to get the Update of the extension directly from my server since chrome's last upgrades.
- Any other way to update my extension is welcomed .

Comment: And why not? What have you tried?

Comment: Script might be relatively tricky though, you'll probably need `unsafe-eval` in the CSP.

Comment: @Xan would you suggest a way that allows me to update the script from my own server if it is possible

Comment: It depends on what kind of code goes in the script.

Comment: my code is simple to read rss feeds and displays it on the on focus user's tab. Does the scripts coe matter ?